# Alternate to hasPermanentMenuKey() for Android 2.3.3

Tags: android, android-menu

I am building my App with API level 10. But it can be installed and used in later versions. I need to show Action Bar only if the device does not have menu button. For Example, Tablets, Google Galaxy Nexus Phone, etc. People suggest to use hasPermanentMenuKey() function. But it is available only after API level 14 I guess. Can anyone suggest me how to get around this issue?

Thanks,
Karthik

Comment: "I need to show Action Bar only if the device does not have menu button" -- please reconsider this plan.

Comment: @CommonsWare: Yes, I thought it's a bad idea. But I have a Nexus S with Android 4.1.2. When I show the default title bar for my application, it looks so weird with my UI design. That's y I added "requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);" statement in my code.

Answer (score 12):

Use Below code :

```
ViewConfiguration.get(context).hasPermanentMenuKey();
```

First set your build target to **API level 14 or UP** that will stop Eclipse from getting Any Error while Using above code.

> **Now Check your API Level**

**Case 1.**  if your API level : **10 and less**

> the device does have hardware menu button.

**Case 2.**  if your API level : **11 to 13(HoneyComb)**

> the device doesn't have HW MENU button, because tablets with Honeycomb
>   doesn't have MENU.

**Case 3.**  if your API level : **14 or Higher**

> If the API level is 14 or higher, you can use hasPermanentMenuKey().

Hope it will some how help you.

Comment: Note that your algorithm will only be accurate for devices that meet the Compatibility Definition Document (CDD). Devices like the Kindle Fire and NOOK series will not meet that specification and therefore will not line up with your algorithm.

Comment: @CommonsWare: yes you are Right. Thank you so much for your valuable correction here. can you suggest me a way to complete my algorithm for working on kindle fire and NOOK series?

Comment: AFAIK, you would have to check exact device models. The 2nd generation Kindle Fire series runs API Level 14+, so `hasPermanentMenuKey()` should work (though I have no idea what those devices return for that). 1st generation Kindle Fire and the NOOKs that I have seen are closest to your 11-to-13 bucket, in that they have their own navigation bar that would have a MENU affordance.

Comment: @CommonsWare: i Really appreciate your answer. i will definitely recommend you while completing this algorithm.Thank you so much once again.

Comment: @Bhavesh & CommonsWare: Thanks for your response. But I know this solution as it is available all over stack overflow. As I mentioned in my question, I am building my app with API level 10. And my target SDK needs to be API level 10. I cannot change them. That's why I posted a new question asking to get around this issue. Like a work around.

Comment: First generation Kindle Fire is API level 10 so it falls into the first pocket. Now if you change "_hardware_ menu button" into "_permanent_ menu key" (not caring if it is hardware or software) then the answer of the algorithm is correct in the sense that your app does not have to provide an alternative solution.

Answer (score 0):

This should work for all devices on the market:

```
public static boolean hasPermanentKeys(Activity activity) {
        //
        int height=0;
        int realHeight=0;

        WindowManager w = activity.getWindowManager();
        Display d = w.getDefaultDisplay();
        DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
        d.getMetrics(metrics);
        // since SDK_INT = 1;
         height = metrics.heightPixels;

    // includes window decorations (statusbar bar/menu bar)
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 14 && Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 17)
            try {
                realHeight = (Integer) Display.class.getMethod("getRawHeight").invoke(d);
            } catch (Exception ignored) {
            }
    // includes window decorations (statusbar bar/menu bar)
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 17)
            try {
                Point realSize = new Point();
                Display.class.getMethod("getRealSize", Point.class).invoke(d, realSize);
                realHeight = realSize.y;
            } catch (Exception ignored) {
            }
        if(height == realHeight){
            return true;
        }
        else{
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

although its an old post but if anyone comes across this here is a solution that could be used from support-v4 library (from library version 24.2.0 it will support upto API-9):

`ViewConfigurationCompat.hasPermanentMenuKey(ViewConfiguration.get(context))`

https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/index.html