# How to determine on screen soft buttons android

Tags: android, uibutton

I am working on android application . In which I have to set image on specific position on screen. Problem comes up when on screen button like in this image comes up![image]

I googled alot but didn't find any help. Is there any way programatically to detect these on screen buttons ?
Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2):

you can check for `hasPermanentMenuKey` using

```
boolean hasMenuKey = ViewConfiguration.get(context).hasPermanentMenuKey();
```

if that returns true it means you dont have the soft keys.

regarding different APIs level don't worry about `honeycomb` because they don't have soft keys, for more read on different APIs [please refer to this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14068529/488434).

> Report if the device has a permanent menu key available to the user.
>
> As of Android 3.0, devices may not have a permanent menu key
>   available. Apps should use the action bar to present menu options to
>   users. However, there are some apps where the action bar is
>   inappropriate or undesirable. This method may be used to detect if a
>   menu key is present. If not, applications should provide another
>   on-screen affordance to access functionality.